# Querying varchars as decimals in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a problem in SQL Server, I am trying to query

```
where x.numbers >= '9'
```

where `x.numbers` was stored as `varchar` and some of the values I have in that field are

```
8.9
9.3
6.7
>10
8.3
>= 9
```

If I try `isnumeric(x.numbers)`, then it is excluding those values that start with > or >=. and I tried `cast(x.numbers as decimal)` but it is not working as well. Please advise

Comment: Could you post some sample data and the result you'd be expect? http://www.sqlservercentral.com/articles/Best+Practices/61537/

Comment: 7.9, 4.5, 9, >10, 6.7, 11.7, >12

Comment: For `>10` and `>12`  say you were asked for values `<=10`, can I safely assume it would need to **EXCLUDE** those values?

Comment: I need to include all the numbers that are >6, whether they are simply a number or they start with >. I don't want to exclude the numbers just because they start with >

Comment: If you need this more often you should try to separate the number and the operator into two columns.

Answer (score 1):

This is my attempt. It's not pretty, but might get you what you're after. It increases/decreases the values of values that have either `<` or `>`:

```
CREATE TABLE #Sample (N varchar(5));
INSERT INTO #Sample
VALUES ('7.9'),('4.5'),('9'),('>10'),('6.7'),('11.7'),('>12'),('<=10'),('<9');
GO

SELECT *
FROM #Sample;
GO
WITH CTE AS (
    SELECT *,
           CASE WHEN N LIKE '>=%' OR N LIKE '<=%' THEN TRY_CONVERT(decimal(5,1),REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(N,'>',''),'<',''),'=',''))
                WHEN N LIKE '>%' THEN TRY_CONVERT(decimal(5,1),REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(N,'>',''),'<',''),'=','')) + 0.1 --Adding .1 as it needs to be more than it's value
                WHEN N LIKE '<%' THEN TRY_CONVERT(decimal(5,1),REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(N,'>',''),'<',''),'=','')) - 0.1
                ELSE TRY_CONVERT(decimal(5,1),N)
           END AS Nr
    FROM #Sample S)
SELECT N
FROM CTE
WHERE Nr >= 9;

GO
DROP TABLE #Sample;

--SQL 2008, just CONVERT
WITH CTE AS (
    SELECT *,
           CASE WHEN N LIKE '>=%' OR N LIKE '<=%' THEN CONVERT(decimal(5,1),REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(N,'>',''),'<',''),'=',''))
                WHEN N LIKE '>%' THEN CONVERT(decimal(5,1),REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(N,'>',''),'<',''),'=','')) + 0.1 --Adding .1 as it needs to be more than it's value
                WHEN N LIKE '<%' THEN CONVERT(decimal(5,1),REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(N,'>',''),'<',''),'=','')) - 0.1
                ELSE CONVERT(decimal(5,1),N)
           END AS Nr
    FROM #Sample S)
SELECT N
FROM CTE
WHERE Nr >= 9;
```

Comment: I have a very large database here that I am querying, I would like to check on the values in the where clause to be less complicated for me. Also the TRY_CONVERT is not working in sql server

Comment: To repeat my other comment, what version of SQL Server are you using? `TRY_CONVERT` was introduced in SQL Server 2012. If you're using SQL Server <=2008 then you could try just `CONVERT()` but if you have any scenarios you haven't given us, it won't work. And the WHERE clause is just `WHERE Nr >= 9`, it can't get much simpler than that! :)

Comment: I've added a (2008) version using `CONVERT`, rather than `TRY_CONVERT`. If you get any errors, you'll need to update your question with more sample data, showing us the ones that are generating errors.

Answer (score 0):

I would use `try_convert()`:

```
 where try_convert(decimal(38, 6), field) > 9
```

Now, this works for many circumstances and assumes that you want to ignore non-numeric values.

You can modify this to get rid of various "other" characters:

```
 where try_convert(decimal(38, 6), replace(replace(replace(replace(field, ' ', ''), '=', ''), '>', ''), '<', '')) > 9
```

This ignores the "operator" characters.

However, your problem is incompletely specified.  If the field were `'< 12'` or `'> 7'` what do you want it to return?

Comment: just the number out of >=7, and try_convert is not a built in function in sql server

Comment: What version of SQL Server are you using? `TRY_CONVERT` was introduced in SQL Server 2012, so yes, it is a "built in function". :)

Comment: I have the 2008, should I download the 2012?

Comment: I usedAND ISNUMERIC(number)=1 and number !='.'
  
)c where cast(number as numeric (5,2))>=6.5

Comment: @sam . . . No, you should download 2016 or 2017.  Use the most recent released version.

Answer (score 0):

try cast(n as float) as shown below:

```
        create table #tmp(numbers varchar(10))

        insert into #tmp values('8.9')
        insert into #tmp values('9.3')
        insert into #tmp values('6.7')
        insert into #tmp values('11')
        insert into #tmp values('8.3')
        insert into #tmp values('9')
        insert into #tmp values('10')


        Select *  from #tmp where cast(numbers as float)> = cast('9' as float)

        Drop table #tmp
```